# Undefined reference to `gtk_menu_bar_append'

Tags: reference, compiler-errors, gtk, undefined, gtk3

I want to define a drop list menu in GTK with following codes:

```
GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_bar_new();
GtkWidget *menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("[Default Locale]");
gtk_menu_bar_append (GTK_MENU_BAR(menu), menuitem);
```

but I get following error:
undefined reference to `gtk_menu_bar_append'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I do not want to use  gtk_menu_shell_append. what should I do?

Comment: How do you compile and link your program? Do you use an IDE or `Makefile` that defines `GTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED`?

Comment: I am using following line:  gcc test.c -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear you were using GTK 3. See Phili Wood's answer, then.

Comment: To add clarification to user48's and Phil's answer, the problem is a GTK2 vs GTK3 version issue.  GTK2 uses gtk_menu_bar_append, while GTK3 uses gtk_menu_shell_append.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [GtkMenuBar documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenuBar.html) there is no such function in Gtk3. GtkMenuBar is derived from GtkMenuShell so you should use gtk_menu_shell_append.